# I can see nums decrementing on the screen display, why won't it break the loop? x86 assembly using nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
    ;store number of accounts to add
    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, nums
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80
        _storeLoop:
        dec byte [nums]

        ;display nums
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE
        mov ebx, STDOUT
        mov ecx, nums
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

        mov eax, [nums]
        cmp eax, 1
        jnz _storeLoop

section.bss
nums resb 1
```

Why am i stuck in this loop. I can see nums equals zero eventually. I've tried using different comparisons like jg.

Comment: `mov eax` reads 4 bytes at the memory address indicated by `[nums]`

Comment: Look at the value in `eax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment above says, `mov eax, [nums]` will read 4 bytes from a memory location holding a 1-byte counter. If the other 3 bytes don't happen to be all zeroed when this loop starts, it will never terminate.